# How can I use Bluetooth UUID to make a device advertise to other devices using my same Mobile application their UUID?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I am working on a social distancing mobile application using BLE. To track people who had contact with a verified coronavirus case. So till now when a device get near another device the distance is measured and the time is written in Section called History. However the user will not be able to identify which device he had contact with because there is nothing to identify each device.
So my question is how can I make a unique ID for each device and take that ID and put it in the History Tab.
I am sorry if my question is not clear enough, I am new to android development.

Comment: how you identify a contact? The BLE signature hasn`t the UUID?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question, I have read about the UUID, I dont know exactly what it is or what it does, but I read that it is a unique ID for each Bluetooth device, so I was wondering. Can I make the mobile application read this ID and put to variable to be used later inside the app.

Comment: The tracer apps I know about are adding a UUID to their advertisement package so other tracer apps can find and store the UUID. But the UUID changes over time for privacy reasons. If you get tested positive and tell the app all your UUID from the last days get marked as 'infected'. If you have scanned one of these you might have been in contact. You can do something similar with a fixed UUID if you really want to do your own app.

Comment: This is the google api used by many official apps: https://developers.google.com/android/exposure-notifications/exposure-notifications-api